# MongoDB directoryperdb option

Tags: mongodb, configuration, chown

I have a MongoDB instance running but **directoryperdb** is false. I would like to enable it.

Is it safe to create and change the owner of folders to keep my data by manually, instead of dump and restore?

I tried on a test environment and it seems mongo working without any problem... But I want to be sure that will be good for production too...

Thanks for help, information, and comments.

Comment: Your English is a bit confusing, can you explain a bit more of what you mean by: "keep my data by manual, instead of dump and restore"?

Comment: as mentioned http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--directoryperdb

there must be directories to keep database files. i created this folders by mkdir, and changed owners to mongodb. then moved db files to folders.

Comment: Ooooh you meant by what it said in the manual? Ok yeah, Derick answers that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that should work just fine - as long as you **shutdown** MongoDB first before moving files around. If you are using a replica set, then you need to do it one by one, and make sure you follow the rolling "upgrades" procedure — ie, makes sure that a node is a secondary first before shutting it down.

Comment: I also found another answer to same problem at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/wPbzG0cFFpg so it works...